# Retaining File Path - Access/VB Common Dialogue DLL

Tags: ms-access

So this issue appears to be unique to me as my coworkers aren't having any issues.

We have an Access DB that we use to upload files to SQL tables via forms.  To choose the file for these forms there is a call in VB for a Common Dialogue DLL (me!File_Location=LaunchCD(Me) is the only code that launches the file explorer ).  Whenever I upload a file, I have to remap to the folder I want every time as it reverts back to the base C drive for me.  I am the only one with this issue as for everyone else it reverts back to the last folder they uploaded a file from.

I've found that people have this issue with internet browser uploading; but haven't come across anyone who is having the same issue as me with Access and it only affecting one person.  If anyone could help it would be much appreciated as I use this program several times a day and it's beginning to get a bit tedious to have to remap to the folder ten times in a row to upload all files.  Thanks!

Comment: What version of Windows?  Do you have access to the code for the LaunchCD function?  This could be an issue with Windows Explorer folder options, like "Launch folder windows in a separate process", "Browse each folder in a separate window", etc.  Compare such settings with the other computers.

Comment: I'm unable to access the code for launchcd unfortunately.  We did discover if I open it in 2013 vs 2010 it works though!  We use 2010 for everything else so it's just an inconsistency I'll have to remember.  Thank you for the help!